# Webpack 4 with sass-loader & resolve-url-loader - Image paths not being found

Tags: webpack, sass-loader, resolve-url-loader

*Minimally reproducible setup here: https://github.com/jamesopti/webpack_playground/tree/resolve_url_loader_issue*

Im trying to use `resolve-url-loader` to add a hashname to my scss `url()` image paths, but I'm having a heck of a time getting it to work with webpack 4.
I have a bunch of images in `/static/img/**` which are referenced in my SCSS like:

```
span.arrow {
  background: url(/static/img/audiences.png);
}
```

Which is ending up in my css as exactly the same thing (resolve-url-loader isnt finding them)

When I run the following configuration through webpack, I see that resolve loader is finding the right `url()` and its path, but debug mode is saying NOT FOUND.

```
resolve-url-loader: /static/img/audiences.png
  /Users/usr1/webpack_playground/src
  /Users/usr1/webpack_playground/static/img
  NOT FOUND
```

Is there some output config thats not correct? I've tried various combinations of the settings to no avail:

```
  loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
  options: {
    debug: true,
    root: path.join(__dirname, './static/img'),
    includeRoot: true,
    absolute: true,
  },
```

My end goal is for file-loader to transform them to the /dist hashed version:

```
span.arrow {
  background: url(/static/img/audiences-dhsye47djs82kdhe6.png);
}
```

// Webpack rules config

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, './static/img'),
        ],
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
          },
        },
      },
      { test: /\/src\/js\/(?:.*)\.css$/, use: [ { loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' } ] },
      {
        test: [/\.scss$/, /\.sass$/],
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
            options: {
              debug: true,
              root: './static/img',
              includeRoot: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              outputStyle: 'compressed',
              sourceMap: true,
              includePaths: [
                './src'
              ],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out all I needed was `file-loader` to do what I wanted.

When an image (matching my specified file extensions) is encountered by any of the css/sass/style loaders, its processed through `file-loader`, which both copies it to the output directory specified with the naming format specified and returns the name for the sass loader to use as the file name.

```js
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
    exclude: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
    ],
    use: {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[path][name]-[hash].[ext]',
        outputPath: '../',
        publicPath: '/dist',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /\.svg$/,
    include: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules'),
    ],
    use: {
      loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
      },
    },
  },
  { test: /\/src\/js\/(?:.*)\.css$/, use: [ { loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' } ] },
  {
    test: [/\.scss$/, /\.sass$/],
    use: [
      MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          sourceMap: true,
          root: path.resolve(__dirname),
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            autoprefixer({
              'browsers': ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 10'],
            }),
          ],
          sourceMap: true,
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
          outputStyle: 'compressed',
          sourceMap: true,
          includePaths: [
            './src/scss',
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'html-loader',
        options: {
          root: path.resolve(__dirname),
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: [
      /\/bundles\/(?:.*)\.js$/,
    ],
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: Do you have the github for this one? I deal with the same problem but I cannot fix it

Answer (score 2):

Actually resolve-url-loader is still needed *sometimes*...
it depends if you want to be able to resolve url() calls from files imported inside the sass compilation. Without it urls would be broken in this case.

But if you don't use multi-file scss build (for example if each component has only 1 scss file local to it without calling shared library scss code or partials of some some sort) - then you don't need resolve-url-loader.

Of course you will still need url-loader (wraps file-loder with inlining abilities) or file-loader (for straight copying of assets to dist folder)

resolve-url-loader works by re-working original files from the sourcemap emitted by sass 
and sass-loader does have an issue with sourcemaps when working with the dart-sass implementaion. In this case sourcemap sources  would mistakenly be stdin inplace of the filename
see [issue 671](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/671) and fix that came in [PR 681](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/pull/681)

this is still unreleased fix as of today (July 2019) , the only option is to work with node-sass or use unreleased sass-loader

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I believe [you need](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) `url-loader` to load the images properly with Webpack 4.  This setup worked for me:

```
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        loader: "url-loader",
    }, {        
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
            "style-loader",
            "css-loader",
            "sass-loader",
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I have tried "url-loader" with webpack 4 and URLs in CSS are not being base64 encoded.

Comment: I linked to the `url-loader` Github in my answer.  There's a note under the header `limit` which describes how to get base64 encoding.